# Panning an image/images in Swift using an iPad compass

Tags: ios, swift, virtual-reality

I have four images; each is 350 pixels wide; I have the text North on the first, East on the second, South on the third and West on the fourth. I put them into a scrollView in a single image and I link said scrollView to the direction I am pointing my iPad. Now as I pan around I want the scroll to pan around the images, so if I am looking north and turn east I see north slide of the screen and east onto it.

Now I tried to do this using the compass, and it works reasonably well, but how to code crossing the boundary between 0 degrees and 360 degrees is a challenge. I tried using yaw so that I am looking at two 180 degree circles, but working out how to make that work has evaded me too. I google this and find quaternion and euler angles, but nothing that makes enough sense to me...

Need some direction/help.

Comment: This question has been answered below, I post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a scroll view for this, since you are controlling the scroll offset by device heading rather than by letting the user swipe the screen. So you could just use a plain old `UIView` as the parent of the image views.  You would just update `view.bounds.origin` instead of `scrollView.contentOffset` to “scroll”. (Under the hood, the scroll view's `contentOffset` is the same as its `bounds.origin`.)

Anyway, lay out your images like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| North |  East | South |  West | North |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Note that the North image is used twice.

When you get a new heading, update the offset of the scroll view like this:

```
let range = CGFloat(350 * 4)
let offset = range * (CGFloat)direction / 360
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(offset, 0)
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly and is way simpler than the code I been fooling around with. **THANKS**, would give two votes if I could for super quick and simple answer.